# ERROR: Service 'ubuntu' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, dockerfile

when I execute the command `docker-compose up --build -d`

I get these errors:

> E: Unable to locate package php7.4 E: Couldn't find any package by
> glob 'php7.4' E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4' E: Unable
> to locate package php7.4-fpm E: Couldn't find any package by glob
> 'php7.4-fpm' E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4-fpm' ERROR:
> Service 'ubuntu' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get
> update     && apt-get install -y curl zip unzip             php7.4
> php7.4-fpm             gettext-base sudo' returned a non-zero code:
> 100

can you help me please what is wrong with my `dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml`?

here is my **`dockerfile`**

```sh
FROM  ubuntu:18.04

# ENV PORT=80
# ENV FPMSTREAM=9000

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y curl zip unzip \
            php7.4 php7.4-fpm \
            gettext-base sudo



COPY ./webapp /var/www/webapp

WORKDIR /var/www/webapp

ADD default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www && \
  chmod -R 775 /var/www && \
  useradd -m docker && echo "docker:docker" | chpasswd && \
  adduser docker sudo

USER docker
```

**`docker-compose.yml`**

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:

  ubuntu:
    build: .
    container_name: ubuntu-container
    external_links:
      - nginx
      - db

  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable
    container_name: nginx-container
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    expose:
      - 9000
    volumes:
      - ./code:/var/www/webapp
      - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: mysql-container
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    expose:
      - 3306
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

Comment: Why don't you just use the base image of docker PHP image? instead of ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is that you're trying to install a version of PHP which is not available in Ubuntu 18.04.

The latest available version is 7.2, so you need to replace `php7.4 php7.4-fpm` with either `php php-fpm` or `php7.2 php7.2-fpm`

Comment: I didn't understand this, If it's mentioned, that he wanted specifically, `php7.4`, then how `php7.2` been accepted as answer

Comment: @nischaygoyal he didn't say he wanted PHP 7.4. He asked for what was wrong with his Dockerfile, and I answered to that question. If he accepted, guess it was because it covered his needs. You didn't answer the question, just said "try this", but an answer is beyond copying and pasting, it's explaining what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below `Dockerfile` for build

```
FROM  ubuntu:18.04

# ENV PORT=80
# ENV FPMSTREAM=9000

#Add Repos for PHP modules
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt -y install software-properties-common \
    && add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php 

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y curl zip unzip \
            php7.4 php7.4-fpm \
            gettext-base sudo



COPY ./webapp /var/www/webapp

WORKDIR /var/www/webapp

ADD default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www && \
  chmod -R 775 /var/www && \
  useradd -m docker && echo "docker:docker" | chpasswd && \
  adduser docker sudo

USER docker
```